# TCL - expect buffer cuts first lines of output

Tags: tcl, buffer, expect

.I made a simple TCL/expect script to capture via regexp some mac-addresses from a command that I usually run on our Wireless Access Controller.

The thing that I dont understand is that I always miss the first 14-15 lines of command's output from the buffer.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
log_file -a -noappend wlac.log
#global spawn_id
set timeout 5
#set exp_internal 1
#exp_internal -f debug_wlac.log 1
match_max 700000 

set userf userfile
#username

set pwdf pwdfile
#password

set commands "sta-all"
#commands = display station all

set hostsls "wlac"
#hostsls= hostnames list

set f [open $userf]
set user [read $f]
close $f

set f [open $pwdf]
set password [read $f]
close $f 

set f [open "$hostsls"]
set hosts [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

set f [open "$commands"]
set commands [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

foreach host $hosts {
    if {[string trim $host] eq ""} then continue
    send_user "\n"
    send_user ">>>>>  Working on $host @ [exec date] <<<<<\n"
    send_user "\n"
    spawn ssh -o GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o AddKeysToAgent=yes "$user@$host"
    expect {
    "assword"
    {
    send "$password\n"
    }
    ">" 
    {
    send \n
    }
    }

    foreach cmd $commands {
    expect {
    ">"
    {
    append  maclist $expect_out(buffer)
    send "$cmd\n"
    }
    "More" 
    {
    append maclist $expect_out(buffer)
    send "\n"
    exp_continue 
    }
    }
    }
    }
    set pattern_mac {[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-][0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-][0-9A-Fa-f]{4}}
    set match_maclist [regexp -all -inline $pattern_mac $maclist]   
    puts "\n"
    puts "***Beginning of Output***"
    puts "\n"
    puts $maclist
    puts "\n"
    puts "***print array elements***"
    puts "\n"
    foreach i $match_maclist { puts $i }
    puts [llength $match_maclist]

    expect ">"
    send "quit\n"
    close
    wait
    send_user "\n"
```

I see from the logs, that I always miss this part, that is more or less the first 14 lines of output after the command "display station all"
The rest of the output buffer has everything that I expect to be there.
I tried enabling the debug log, but I didn't notice anything strange.

```
<wlac-hostname>display station all
Rf/WLAN: Radio ID/WLAN ID                                                     
Rx/Tx: link receive rate/link transmit rate(Mbps)                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STA MAC          AP ID AP name                       Rf/WLAN  Band  Type  Rx/Tx      RSSI  VLAN  IP address   SSID                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
aaaa-bbbb-cc11   1111  AP-HOSTNAME                   1/1      5G    11n   130/117    -55   1111  1.1.1.1      ssid-name
aaaa-bbbb-cc11   1111  AP-HOSTNAME                   1/1      5G    11n   130/117    -55   1111  1.1.1.1      ssid-name
aaaa-bbbb-cc11   1111  AP-HOSTNAME                   1/1      5G    11n   130/117    -55   1111  1.1.1.1      ssid-name
aaaa-bbbb-cc11   1111  AP-HOSTNAME                   1/1      5G    11n   130/117    -55   1111  1.1.1.1      ssid-name
aaaa-bbbb-cc11   1111  AP-HOSTNAME                   1/1      5G    11n   130/117    -55   1111  1.1.1.1      ssid-name
aaaa-bbbb-cc11   1111  AP-HOSTNAME                   1/1      5G    11n   130/117    -55   1111  1.1.1.1      ssid-name
aaaa-bbbb-cc11   1111  AP-HOSTNAME                   1/1      5G    11n   130/117    -55   1111  1.1.1.1      ssid-name
aaaa-bbbb-cc11   1111  AP-HOSTNAME                   1/1      5G    11n   130/117    -55   1111  1.1.1.1      ssid-name
aaaa-bbbb-cc11   1111  AP-HOSTNAME                   1/1      5G    11n   130/117    -55   1111  1.1.1.1      ssid-name
aaaa-bbbb-cc11   1111  AP-HOSTNAME                   1/1      5G    11n   130/117    -55   1111  1.1.1.1      ssid-name
aaaa-bbbb-cc11   1111  AP-HOSTNAME                   1/1      5G    11n   130/117    -55   1111  1.1.1.1      ssid-name
```

(ip, hostname, and other stuff are just examples)

After this point, everything is ok.
I did a check, and this isn't happening where there is a "---- More ----" but way before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the expect input buffer is too small, which is why you have `match_max 700000`. Unfortunately, this has no effect as it applies to the currently spawned process, of which there is none.

You need to set at the start the **default** size, for future spawn commands by using:

```
match_max -d 700000
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem, I spent hours trying to figure this out.
I found the "match_max" function, but I didn't find/know there was the "-d" switch that is about the default value.

I modified the script accordingly and I can capture all the mac-addresses on the list.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest, if your goal is get the list of MACs, that you don't need to accumulate the entire output:

```
# ... initial stuff

set maclist {}

foreach host $hosts {
    if {[string trim $host] eq ""} then continue

    # using the builtin `timestamp` command
    send_user "\n>>>>>  Working on $host @ [timestamp -format %c] <<<<<\n\n"

    spawn ssh -o GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o AddKeysToAgent=yes "$user@$host"

    expect {
        "assword" { send "$password\n"; exp_continue }
        ">"
    }

    foreach cmd $commands {
        send "$cmd\r"
        expect {
            -re {\y[[:xdigit:]]{4}-[[:xdigit:]]{4}-[[:xdigit:]]{4}\y} {
                lappend maclist $expect_out(0,string)
                exp_continue 
            }
            "More" {
                send "\n"
                exp_continue 
            }
            ">" 
        }
    }
}

puts ""
puts "MAC list"
puts [join $maclist \n]
```

This implies that you don't need to change `match_max`. Be aware of this from the expect manual:

> Note that excessively large           values [of `match_max`] can slow down the pattern matcher.

Comment: This is indeed a clever note, thank you.
Processing the regexp directly in the output is clearly a smarter way to approach the problem.
I'm also grateful to meuh, because I didn't find the "-d" switch on "match_max" even after a long research.